# Tweeting from iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter, oauth

I was wondering if anyone had any success with creating an application and being able to post to Twitter from within the application. I have been looking at dev.twitter.com and am a bit confused about OAuth and how I would get this to work in my app.

I am currently trying to create an application on twitter's website, but it is asking me about a callback URL. I thought you simply could put in AppName:// and this would be okay. I know you then have to add some stuff to the plist. I just am not finding the right documentation for this.

I want to simply post using HTTP POST methods, but I need the authorization part.

Can someone send me in the right direction or send me a link to an example of this. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has also publicly announced Twitter support in iOS 5.  However, I can't go into any of the specific about that (since iOS5 is still under NDA).  If you have an Apple Development account - check this out:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20140824013302/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW14

Comment: I am a registered developer, but this application is needing to be released before iOS 5 is released. I wish I could just use the built in Twitter stuff from iOS 5

Comment: Twitter Framework has been replaced with [Social Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/social) in iOS 6

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement a custom URL scheme for your app before the AppName:// link will work. Documentation for this is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW50).

The alternative is to use a framework such as [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/) to do a lot of the leg work for you.

Comment: I am trying to use ShareKit, it is working fine for Facebook, but the twitter section is not working because it is telling me that  my callback url is wrong. I get this message "Your SHKTwitter config is incorrect. You must set you application type to Browser and define a callback url. SEe SHKConfig.h for more information.

However, I do not see anything in that file and have no clue what to do about this.

Answer (score 0):

Callback URL is important only for web application. It has not meaning for iOS apps according to twitter docs.

A drop in solution is using  [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/)
It supports twitter plus some other social networks.

Comment: I am trying to use ShareKit, it is working fine for Facebook, but the twitter section is not working because it is telling me that  my callback url is wrong. I get this message "Your SHKTwitter config is incorrect. You must set you application type to Browser and define a callback url. SEe SHKConfig.h for more information.

However, I do not see anything in that file and have no clue what to do about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to make outbound tweets you can use the API which is being introduced with iOS 5 to send them. You can find it in the Xcode 4.2/iOS 5 beta.

https://web.archive.org/web/20110806023302/http://www.apple.com:80/ios/ios5/features.html

This does have the disadvantage of being only available to devices running iOS 5 and probably will not be out for a month or two.  But this may fit with your schedule.

Comment: Sorry it unfortunately does not fit with my schedule. I wish I could use it in my app but the app is needed before September 31, and well I do not expect iOS 5 before then unfortunately.

Comment: checkout MGTwitterEngine too. It's an obj-c API for twitter integration. it's a little intense but might be what you need.